# ASP.Net shopping cart application

Tags: asp.net, shopping-cart

I am trying to create an C# / asp.net shopping cart application from scratch (the intention is to understand the layout and the functionality).

Any idea where I can get ideas about how to create a basic simple shopping cart app?
I know there is alot of information out there, but I wanted to get some word of mouth referrals.

Thanks

Comment: Are you partial to ASP.NET classic or ASP.NET MVC? There is an excellent shopping cart tutorial in Apress Pro Asp.net MVC Framework (http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-Framework-Steven-Sanderson/dp/1430210079/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1250823947&sr=8-1)

Comment: Have a look at nopCommerce - [www.nopCommerce.com](http://www.nopCommerce.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several starter kits available on the ASP.NET website which should give you a decent starting point.

http://www.asp.net/community/projects/

Answer (score 3):

Here's several links found some doing a simple search on it:

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/05/aspnet-creating-shopping-cart-example.html

http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2005/03/22/60166.aspx

http://www.sitepoint.com/article/net-shopping-cart-datatables/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/build-a-shopping-cart-in-aspnet/

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Developing-Shopping-Cart.aspx